# Why does `GCC 10 -Wtype-limits` not warn about comparison with `inline static constexpr` expressions when GCC 7 does?

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings, constexpr

When compiling this snippet of code (example code)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>

#ifndef USE_DEFINE
class ClassA
{
    public:
        inline static constexpr uint8_t A = 0;

};
#else
#define A 0
#endif

int main()
{
    srand(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

    uint8_t a = rand() % 255;


#ifndef USE_DEFINE
    if(a < ClassA::A)
#else
    if(a < A)
#endif
    {
        std::cout << "Shouldn't even compile using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wpedantic` flags." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with GCC 7.5 and the following flags

`g++ -std=gnu++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wfatal-errors -Werror -o test main.cc`

i get the following warning/error (due to `-Werror`):

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:40:7: error: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
   40 |  if(a < ClassA::A)
```

Which seems ok to me due to the fact that i'm trying to check if an `uint8_t` is less than `0`. The same happens when defining `USE_DEFINE`. Both expressions are not constant due to the changing value of `a` so it could be checked if the type limits allow this kind of comparison to evaluate as `true` AND `false`.

Doing the same with a newer compiler (GCC 10.1.0 / CLang 10.0.1) i don't get this warning anymore when using the `inline static constexpr uint8_t A = 0` of `ClassA`. When i use `USE_DEFINE` the same happens.

Is this behaviour of GCC/Clang erroneous or is this some sideeffect caused by attributes of `const/constexpr`?

The GCC-Manual says (for GCC 6.4/7.5 as well as 10):

> `-Wtype-limits`
>
> Warn if a comparison is always true or always false due to the limited range of the data type, but do not warn for constant expressions. For example, warn if an unsigned variable is compared against zero with < or >=. This warning is also enabled by -Wextra.

As far as i can see `if(a < ClassA::A)` isn't a constant expression even though i'm using the `constexpr` keyword. The same happens when using `const` instead of `constexpr`. What does lead to this behaviour?

Comment: Why does the error message say `(a < A)` instead of `(a < ClassA::A)` even though you didn't define `USE_DEFINE`?

Comment: I'm sorry, copied the wrong error line. Checked in multiple terminals to have all versions visible.